# RadioButtons with round circles

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was struggling to make the RadioButtons widget look presentable. Either the circles were not round, or the frame had a totally wrong shape, or both (see pictures below, and also [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66510212/how-to-place-widgets-axes-with-equal-aspect-and-requested-size)). So I had created a function that draws a reasonably good-looking one. It works (I have tested for the different number of options, font sizes, and canvas sizes), but feels very manual, there are some constants that I cannot make sense of (but it works!) Any comments welcome.

How it looks now
[image]

How it looked before

[image]

My code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import RadioButtons

#left, bottom = rax_left, 0
def place_ratiobuttons(options, font_size, left, bottom, bg_color, frame_zorder=-.5, active_option=0):
  fig = plt.gcf()
  figure_width_height_ratio = fig.get_size_inches()[0] / fig.get_size_inches()[1]
  renderer = plt.gcf().canvas.get_renderer()

  size_ax = len(options) * font_size / 200 * (figure_width_height_ratio if figure_width_height_ratio < 1 else 1)
  frame_location = [left, bottom , size_ax/figure_width_height_ratio, size_ax]

  axes_ = plt.axes(frame_location)
  rb = RadioButtons(axes_, options, active=active_option)
  all_widgets.append(rb) 

  for circle in rb.circles: # adjust radius here. The default is 0.05
    circle.set_radius(0.2/len(options))

  inverted_rb_axes = rb.ax.transData.inverted()
  max_x1 = 0
  for label_ in rb.labels: # adjust radius here. The default is 0.05
    label_bbox = label_.get_window_extent(renderer=renderer).transformed(inverted_rb_axes)
    max_x1 = max(max_x1, label_bbox.x1)
  max_x1 += font_size / 100
  max_x1 *= size_ax / figure_width_height_ratio

  axes_.set_frame_on(False)
  new_frame = plt.Rectangle(xy=frame_location[:2],
                                  width=max_x1, 
                                  height=size_ax, ec='black', linewidth=plt.rcParams['axes.linewidth'],
                                  color=bg_color, zorder=frame_zorder, transform=fig.transFigure, figure=fig)
  fig.patches += [new_frame]

  return rb, new_frame

font_size = 20
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': font_size})

rb_options = [''.join(['M'*(k+3)])+str(k) for k in range(20)]
all_widgets = []

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8), dpi=50)

rax_left = .05
for c_, bg_color  in enumerate(['cyan', 'pink', 'aliceblue']):

  rb, new_frame = place_ratiobuttons(options=rb_options[:c_*2+3], font_size=font_size, left=rax_left, bottom=0, bg_color=bg_color, frame_zorder=-.5, active_option=0)

  rax_left += new_frame.get_width() + .05

plt.show()
```

Comment: Are you constrained to using Matplotlib for a UI? This doesn't seem very practical. I would stick to using Matplotlib for plots and something else (tkinter, etc.) for UI. Are there constraints preventing this approach?

Comment: It has to work in a web-based GUI replit.com, I am not sure if I can use tkinter there, but I will look into this, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Reinderien I have to have the button and the graph on the same figure, this is definitely a constraint!

Comment: Can you link to the applicable repl.it entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use four-space indentation instead of two
- Try not to rely on `gcf`. Pass around figures explicitly.
- Unpack the return of `get_size_inches` to a width and a height rather than using indexing.
- Replace your ternary with a call to `min`.
- Why are you underscore-suffixing some variable names? This does not seem necessary.
- Your `for`-loop calculating `max_x1` can be replaced with one call to `max` using a generator.
- Add type hints.
- Move your global code into functions. One side-effect is that `all_widgets` will no longer be in the global namespace. You can instead form this from the return of a generator function.
- Rather than creating a list literal and using the `+=` operator, you can just call `.append` on `patches`.
- This:

```
''.join(['M'*(k+3)])+str(k)
```

doesn't work quite the way you think it does. Using the multiplication operator on a string returns a string already, so `join` is not needed.

- For your background colours, prefer an immutable tuple instead of a list.

### Suggested

```py
from typing import Collection, Tuple, Iterable

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from matplotlib.widgets import RadioButtons


def place_ratiobuttons(
    fig: Figure,
    options: Collection[str],
    font_size: int,
    left: float,
    bottom: float,
    bg_color: str,
    frame_zorder: float = -.5,
    active_option: int = 0,
) -> Tuple[RadioButtons, Rectangle]:
    width, height = fig.get_size_inches()
    figure_width_height_ratio = width / height
    size_ax = len(options) * font_size / 200 * min(1, figure_width_height_ratio)
    frame_location = [left, bottom, size_ax/figure_width_height_ratio, size_ax]

    axes = fig.add_axes(rect=frame_location)
    axes.set_frame_on(False)
    rb = RadioButtons(axes, options, active=active_option)

    for circle in rb.circles:  # adjust radius here. The default is 0.05
        circle.set_radius(0.2/len(options))

    inverted_rb_axes = rb.ax.transData.inverted()
    renderer = fig.canvas.get_renderer()

    max_x1 = max(
        label
        .get_window_extent(renderer=renderer)
        .transformed(inverted_rb_axes)
        .x1
        for label in rb.labels
    )
    max_x1 = (max_x1 + font_size/100) * size_ax / figure_width_height_ratio

    new_frame = plt.Rectangle(
        xy=frame_location[:2],
        width=max_x1,
        height=size_ax, ec='black', linewidth=plt.rcParams['axes.linewidth'],
        color=bg_color, zorder=frame_zorder, transform=fig.transFigure, figure=fig,
    )
    fig.patches.append(new_frame)

    return rb, new_frame


def make_buttons(fig: Figure) -> Iterable[RadioButtons]:
    font_size = 20
    plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': font_size})

    rb_options = [
        'M'*(k + 3) + str(k)
        for k in range(20)
    ]
    rax_left = .05

    for c_index, bg_color in enumerate(('cyan', 'pink', 'aliceblue')):
        rb, new_frame = place_ratiobuttons(
            fig=fig,
            options=rb_options[:c_index*2 + 3],
            font_size=font_size,
            left=rax_left,
            bottom=0,
            bg_color=bg_color,
        )
        yield rb
        rax_left += new_frame.get_width() + .05


def main() -> None:
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8), dpi=50)
    all_widgets = list(make_buttons(fig))
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```